# Firebase - set priority when doing an update/fanout to several nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing to several parts/nodes of my Firebase database in one update. Is it possible to set the priority of a node when doing this? Example:

```
firebaseRef.update([
    "/some/node/": "value",
    "/some/other/node": "other value"
])
```

What if I want to set the priority of the node at "/some/other/node" at the same time. Is that possible? Something like:

```
firebaseRef.update([
    "/some/node/": "value",
    "/some/other/node": {
        value: "other value",
        priority:  0 - Date.now()
    }
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it, the "magic" property is named `.priority`:

```
firebaseRef.update([
    "/some/node/": "value",
    "/some/other/node": {
        value: "other value",
        ".priority":  0 - Date.now()
    }
]
```

Note that there aren't really a lot of reasons to use priorities anymore in Firebase. Adding a normally named property (e.g. `"reversedTimestamp": 0 - Date.now()`) will accomplish the same and is less hidden/magic.

### Update

It seems you want to update the node's value, not a child named value. To set the (primitive) value and priority in one go, use:

```
firebaseRef.update([
    "/some/node/": "value",
    "/some/other/node": {
        ".value": "other value",
        ".priority":  0 - Date.now()
    }
]);
```

Comment: Regarding not using priorities, I think it's a convenient way to fix a default sort order that isn't based on the name of the node

Comment: I have noticed a problem with this approach. If I include the ".priority" property, my validation rule for that node fails. The value is a boolean, and my validation rules is "newData.isBoolean()". This fails if I include .priority. If I just do "/some/other/nodes": true everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using:

```
".priority": Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

It creates a timestamp from the server. It makes sure that our data is in the order it was created in, even if our clients are in different time zones.

Comment: How does this work if the priority is supposed to be the date in descending order, i.e. the newest date at the top?

Comment: @andlin you could get the array of objects and reverse it. I think that should help.