# Firebase setWithPriority results in Firebase.update failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write data to the Firebase Database with a given Priority, in order to then retrieve the childs in reversed order than they are currently in. The following I got from the [answer of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order) regarding this issue:

```
var postData = {
    url: urlvar
  };

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().push();//.key;
  newPostKey.setWithPriority(postData, 0 - Date.now());

  var updates = {};

  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + '/urls/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

However, when trying to trigger this, I'm getting (from the extensions popup console):

> Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key

Which argument is meant by that, what exactly is wrong here?

What did work, before I tried to set a priority, was simply the code above but newPostKey was attached a key:

```
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying around different approaches I have found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042529/firebase-set-priority-when-doing-an-update-fanout-to-several-nodes) where I can just add the priority to the postData, and then write it to the DB:

```
  var postData = {
    url: urlvar,
    ".priority":  0 - Date.now()
  };

  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
```

Comment: Note that (while still functional and not deprecated) there is no reason to use priorities for this. Adding a property named `invertedData` you can accomplish the same and get a more explicit data structure (`.priority` is hidden from most views/values).